# JQuery Memory Leak: How to Automatically destroy select2 in child nodes before calling .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, jquery-select2

I am working on large single page application build on JQuery, ajax.

Found that, not destroying select2 properly will lead to memory leak.

So for every time we call `html()` on node in ajax callback, we have to find and destroy select2 binded to child of that node.

Currently we doing like this,

```js
function unbindSelect2(parentNode) {
  if( parentNode.length ){
 parentNode.find(".select2-hidden-accessible").select2('destroy');
  }
}


function callback1(data) {
  unbindSelect2($("#node1");
  $("#node1").html(data);
}
```

Is there any better way to automatically `unbind select2` on every call to `.html`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the method `.select2('destroy')` is the only way to free memory.

It reverts changes to DOM done by Select2. The good news is that any selection done via Select2 will be preserved.